# extract the last week data from the data frame and find the max value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I Have a following data frame, I want to extract the last one week data and find the max value of that week, how do I do that?

```
Date        Value
2020-10-4   2768
2020-10-3   3032
2020-10-2   2264
2020-10-1   2723
2020-10-0   3407
2020-10-1   11660
2020-10-2   13551
2020-10-3   8031
2020-10-4   8183
2020-10-5   6186
2020-10-6   9394
2020-10-7   11498
2020-10-8   43214
2020-10-9   5538
2020-10-10  21590
2020-10-11  5356
2020-10-12  8371
2020-10-13  21999
2020-10-14  11729
2020-10-15  11983
2020-10-16  6056
2020-10-17  13360
2020-10-18  12258
2020-10-19  11437
2020-10-20  10506
2020-10-21  39793
2020-10-22  1131
2020-10-23  1356
2020-10-24  6891
2020-10-25  57736
2020-10-26  14274
2020-10-27  3884
2020-10-28  12164
2020-10-29  6936
2020-10-30  11705
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.last.html) with `max`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

m = df.set_index('Date')['Value'].last('W').max()
print (m)
14274
```

EDIT:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

s = df.set_index('Date')['Value'].last('W')
print (s)
Date
2020-10-26    14274
2020-10-27     3884
2020-10-28    12164
2020-10-29     6936
2020-10-30    11705
Name: Value, dtype: int64

df = s[s == s.max()].reset_index()
print (df)
        Date  Value
0 2020-10-26  14274
```

EDIT: If need last 7 days:

```
s = df.set_index('Date')['Value'].last('7d')
print (s)
Date
2020-10-24     6891
2020-10-25    57736
2020-10-26    14274
2020-10-27     3884
2020-10-28    12164
2020-10-29     6936
2020-10-30    11705
Name: Value, dtype: int64

df = s[s == s.max()].reset_index()
print (df)
        Date  Value
0 2020-10-25  57736
```

If need last 7 days from today:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

df = df[(pd.Timestamp('now').floor('d') - df['Date']).dt.days < 7]

df = df[df['Value'] == df['Value'].max()]
print (df)
         Date  Value
32 2020-10-28  12164
```

Comment: Thanks but i want the entire rows as an output

Comment: 2020-10-26  14274

Comment: @jezrael I'd be interested in knowing what's the fastest to filter the last 7 days (between your method and mine which was based on the .isin(set(...)) method) ?

Comment: @tgrandje - hmmm, obviously arithmetic operations are faster, but also the best test in real data.

Comment: I have tested the filtering (not the .max) with timeit (creating a random dataframe of 10.000 rows). I get 3.9 ms with your method, 1.31ms with mine (both tests including creating a copy of the dataframe btw). I suspect this lagtime might be due to the .to_datetime method, which I have always found to be quite long...

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing first is creating a set of the dates you want to select, and then filter the dataframe using it.
This should do the trick (that is, if your dates are at the datetime format...)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
today = dt.date.today()
last_week = {today-dt.timedelta(x) for x in range(7)}
df = df[df.Date.isin(last_week)]
max = df[df.Date==df.Date.max()]
print(df)
print(max)
```